# Error while activating custom feature

Tags: feature-activation, feature-receiver

I have a wsp package installed as farm solution. package has event reciever on activating feature. When I go to Site Collection Features and activate this feature i get an error

```
     Error
     File Not Found.
     Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
     Correlation ID: 958eb25f-0b7b-423c-a8da-95ce43cdae0d

     Date and Time: 10/8/2012 2:51:21 PM
```

I cant find corelation ID in 14/LOGS. I don't understand the error.

What cause the issue?

Updated:

Elements.xml from CAB

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
              <Module Url="_catalogs/wp" List="113" Name="PCenter"> 
                  <File Url="Processing_Center.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Path="PCenter\ProcessingCenter.webpart"> 
                     <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom"/> 
                  </File>  
              </Module> 
           </Elements>
```

manifest.xml from CAB

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
           <Module Name="PCenter" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
              <File Path="PCenter\ProcessingCenter.webpart" Url="Processing_Center.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
               <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
              </File>
           </Module>
        </Elements>
```

feature.xml from CAB

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Description="Web Part for Displaying Server Errors" Id="83cd6230-f065-4990-a54e-50975a539076" ReceiverAssembly="PCenter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=307cd31083df2d5c" ReceiverClass="PCenter.Features.Feature1.Feature1EventReceiver" Scope="Site" Title="Processing Center">
           <ElementManifests>
             <ElementManifest Location="PCenter\Elements.xml" />
               <ElementFile Location="PCenter\ProcessingCenter.webpart" />
             </ElementManifests>
           </Feature>
```

Comment: Please provide some more details, with only this much detail only wild guess is possible, provide your feature.xml file and any other details, one wild guess I can give you right now - are you deploying your assemblies to GAC? if not then please do so and check if this error appears

Comment: As Diptarag said, we need more info. The problem isn't specific to one thing, it could be a missing module file, a missing page/list/other reference in codebehind, etc... You should try to include some info about the feature structure, possibly with some code snipped from the event receiver.

Comment: I guess i deploy it to Gac (see updates above <Assembly Location="PCenter.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache"> )

Answer (score 1):

For general troubleshooting for errors like this you can perform the following steps:

- Make sure that diagnostic logging in CA is set to verbose (CA - Monitoring - Reporting - Configure diagnostic logging)
- Using SharePoint Log Viewer found at http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/ enable live farm monitoring.  The icon looks like the "play" button in the tool bar.

  - Activate your custom site collection feature and wait for the error message.
  - Go back to SharePoint Log Viewer and pause the live monitoring.

This will show you only the relevant logs for you to look at.  Pay particular attention to items of Level "Unexpected".

If the correlation ID or the error messages still do not appear in the log then perhaps you may be looking in the wrong folder.  Sometimes the log files are stored in a different folder.  This can also be verified from CA site.

Please provide the Element XML it will help with identifying the issue.

Comment: Thank you, 
I checked all categories and set critical event to report to the event log and trace log to verbose and saved it. But still can't fild correlation ID in 14/LOGS.In Sharepoint Log Viewer my Correlation ID didn't appear... Trace Log appear here %CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\ as mentioned in CA

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to activate an event receiver feature in a site that doesn't have the list created -and needed- where the event receiver is attached. Check twice that the list exists.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the IIS virtual directory nd modify the web.config file. Set

```
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
     CallStack="true"
     <compilation batch="false" debug="true">
```

This way you will get a more useful error which can help in identifying the real issue.

Comment: I have already done it. But stil get this short message

Comment: Then configure diagnostic logging in your CA site by following Central Administration - Monitoring - Reporting - Configure diagnostic logging - SharePoint Foundation. Set Least critical event to report to the trace log  to verbose. Try activating the feature and look for the correlation ID in logs.

Comment: I checked all categories and set critical event to report to the event log and trace log to verbose and saved it. But still can't fild correlation ID in 14/LOGS

Comment: try to reset IIS

Answer (score 0):

Deploy this solution to the same Web Application of the Site Collection where you are trying to activate this Feature.

This issue generally arises if the assemblies which are referenced in the solution are missing at virtual directory of the Web Application (Usually assemblies in 'Bin' folder of the IIS Web Application, C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\\bin)

-- Hope this might help someone out there as this post is quite old.